# When MVC IIS Publish I Can't See My Web Application, File directory is visible. What should I do?

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, indexing, publish

I developed a SQL Management supported web application with ASP.NET CORE MVC technology.
After completing the application completely, I researched and published it on the internet in order to present it in my own locale. I preferred to use IIS in Publish management. Although my steps are the same as for videos and documents, when I run my web application on the local network, what I see is not the application, but the published directories I obtained in the project file under the wwroot folder. My index page is defined on the layout and when I run the application through Visual Studio, there is no problem in the application operation. How can I see my index page with IIS after publishing?

[image]

And I looked the project in Properties\PublishProfiles\IISProfile.pubxml file is giving a warnings like this pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About how to publish mvc application in iis you can refer to this link:

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying to Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).

[Getting Started With IIS Host And Publish In MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-iis-host-and-publish-in-mvc-5).

[ASP.NET MVC 5 - Deployment On Windows IIS Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-deployment-on-windows-iis-server).

If you publish it successfully, please check your default document, about how to configure the default document you can refer to this link: [How to Configure the Default Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/configure-default-document-iis#how-to-configure-the-default-document).

[image]

Comment: okey thanks I am trying now this solutions. And I will tell the result.

Comment: Okey I am trying still, I can see my application, but when something happens to the databse, for example when logging in it throws an error.
At least I can see the app now, it used to be gone too. I'm working on this problem now @samwu

Comment: If it solves the problem, please let me know.

Comment: no ı am trying still. If it works, I will wtire here.  @samwu

Comment: Hi Sam, first of all thank you for your help. I can see the application now, but when I am going to perform a database related operation, for example, when I need to login, I get the following error.

Comment: Server Error in Application '/InventoryPanel'.Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred while executing the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.  Source Error: An unhandled exception was thrown while executing the current web request. Information about the source and location of the exception can be determined using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Try to change the ApplicationPoolIdentity from IIS -> Application Pools -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Identity -> LocalSystem. This will make your application run under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, which is an existing login for the database by default.

Comment: Hi @samwu, ı can't from IIS but, I changed from SQL Management Studio, And I wrote page up pic. How Can solve this problem?

Comment: thank you for interest and advice. I solved this problem. It's working:)